# Reachability - earlier versions

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotifications, reachability

I would alert the user when the connection with a web server is lost. I think the Apple Reachability class could solve my problem, but I would build for ios < 4.

So, my question is: where could I find earlier version of reachability?

Is it possible  to build for ios < 4 with reachability ver 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

yes, why not, I think the Reachability code does not change much, you just need to select your build deployment target to the earlier version, keeping the base SDK to the latest one, and you are fine.

Comment: I know that. But for some reasons, I would build the code for 3.1. Moreover, how could I know if selecting a deployment target to an earlier version (for example 3.1) the program would have a right behavior as on the Reachability page the runtime ios have to be at least ios 3.2?